# Non-trivial ways for generating matrices $A$ for which $A + A^T$ is positive-definite?

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, determinants

**Disclaimer:** This might be an SE question, but I'm not quite sure...

Thanks in advance!

## Setup

So, it is known (see [Proposition 5.2](http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/tsat/files/PmatricesLectureNotes.pdf)) that if $A + A^T$ is positive-definite then $A$ must be a $P$-matrix. Thus this gives a simple way for generating P-matrices (which are otherwise very complex objects, due to the "principal minors" conditions defining them)

## Question

- What (if any ) interesting things can be said about matrices $A$ for which $A + A^T$ is p.d. ?
- What are some interesting non-trivial ways for generating such matrices (i.e matrices for which $A + A^T$ is p.d) ?

Comment: isn't it true that for any real square $A$ it holds that $A$ is positive definite iff $A+A^T$ is positive definite?

Comment: Hum, I see your point. Indeed, $x^T(A + A^T)x = x^TAx + x^TA^Tx = x^TAx + x^TAx = 2x^TAx \ge 0 \iff x^TAx \ge 0$. But for positive definiteness, there is also the symmetry condition which has to be satisfied. But then, there are non-symmetric matrices $A$ for which $x^TAx \ge 0$ with equality iff $x=0$. forgot the the name of such matrices. Thus your claim is not (very) true, except perhaps you're using a definition of +ve definiteness which is different from the standard one.

Comment: I am probably missing something, but can't you just generate an arbitrary positive definite real symmetric matrix $B$ and then choose $A_{nm}$ randomly $\in\mathbb{R}$ for $n\leq m$, followed by $A_{mn}=B_{nm}-A_{nm}$.

Comment: I deleted my answer because @CarloBeenakker 's comment already said it. To sample a symmetric positive definite matrix, one could e.g. pick a diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ with positive entries, a [random orthogonal matrix](http://home.lu.lv/~sd20008/papers/essays/Random%20unitary%20[paper].pdf) $Q$, and a random upper triangular matrix $U$ to set $A = Q \Lambda Q^T + U - U^T$.

Comment: @student: This is indeed an interesting sub-family of such matrices. Thanks. Thanks to Carlo too. Indeed, in general, any squared matrix of the form $A=B+C-C^T$ where $B$ is p.d. (no conditions on $C$) should do the job since $A+A^T=B+C-C^T + B + C^T-C = 2B$ which is p.d. BTW, if think your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @dohmatob True, but if you pick a full $C$, you have in some sense too many degrees of freedom. Anyway, I think we learned that $A = B + C$ with $B$ pos. def. and $C$ skew-symmetric. Now to show that this is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: @student Good points. I also feel such a characterization should hold, though I've not yet tried proving the other direction (necessity).

Comment: @dohmatob Any matrix $A$ can be decomposed into symmetric and skew-symmetric parts, $A = (A + A^T)/2 + (A - A^T)/2$ ...

Comment: Oops! ya sure. Should have thought of that. Thanks.